# Nested eval in ROS2 XML launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find out if it's possible to load a parameter file in an XML launch file, where the path is computed from an arg. This requires nested (or chained) evals:

- The arg has the name of a robot
- Adding a suffix to that gives the name of the package that has the parameter file
- Then we need to call find-pkg-share
- And add another string to get the full file path

Is this possible? What would go into `<param from="...">`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366383/nested-eval-in-ros2-xml-launch-file/) by [nnmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/59904/nnmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2020-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I still don't know how to do nested evals, but this particular problem can be solved without eval, e.g.:

```
<arg name="robot_name" />
<let name="param_file" value="$(find-pkg-share $(var robot_name)_description)/config/robot_params.yaml "/>
<param from="$(var param_file)" />
```

---

Originally posted by [nnmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/59904/nnmm/) with karma: 351 on 2020-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1